# 16,000 geocoding requests with 9 downloads in 4 days: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I am using [Google's Reverse Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) in my app which has been downloaded 9 times in the 4 days since it was released.

The reverse geocoding takes place only after tapping a link in the app.

Today, when I clicked on the link, the address didn't load.

When I checked the Google Cloud Console, I was surprised to find that the API has been called more than 16,138 times in the last 4 days. Furthermore, the number is increasing by hundreds every hour even when the limit has been reached and the 'Show Address' link has stopped loading the address.

It is inconceivable that 9 users would have clicked the 'Show Address' link that many times in the last 4 days and are continuing to click the link even when it has stopped loading the address.

My questions are:

- Is this a common/known problem?
- Does this mean that some attackers may have got access to my API key? (although I must add that this is extremely improbable since I absolutely didn't share the key with anybody in the last 4 days).
- What can I do to find out the origin IP of these requests?
- What measures should I take to control the situation?

Comment: It's impossible to say from what you've said here.

Comment: How are you making requests, and when?

Comment: Are you using web services or Maps Javascript API? Did you protect your API key? I would suggest reading this post: https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices.

Comment: I would suggest that you file a support case via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support in order to open personalized communication channel with Google Maps Tech Support as they can help you better with the issue.